# Contine statement to force the next iteration of the outer loop to take place

Tags: c

How can i give the continue statement to force the next iteration of the outer loop to take place?

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(name1);i++) // Outer Loop
     {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(name2);j++) //inner Loop
        {
           if(name1[i]==name2[j])
           {
                name1[i]='*';
                continue; //If i continue here the  inner loops's newxt iteration takes place
           }
        }    
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(name1);i++) // Outer Loop
     {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(name2);j++) //inner Loop
        {
           if(name1[i]==name2[j])
           {
                name1[i]='*';
                break; // <-- break out of loop
           }
        }    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer by acme is perfectly correct for your code.** & that should be accepted answer. I just want to address a case, when there is some more code after inner loop.

Original code:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(name1);i++) // Outer Loop
{
    for(j=0;j<strlen(name2);j++) //inner Loop
    {
        if(name1[i]==name2[j])
        {
            name1[i]='*';
            continue; //If i continue here the  inner loops's newxt iteration takes place
        }
    }
    // <some more code here....>
}
```

Change it to:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(name1);i++) // Outer Loop
{
    for(j=0;j<strlen(name2);j++) //inner Loop
    {
        if(name1[i]==name2[j])
        {
            name1[i]='*';
            break; // come out of inner loop.
        }
    }
    if(j<strlen(name2)) // check if there was a conditional break.
        continue; // skip remaining code, after inner for loop.
    // <some more code here....>
}
```

NOTE1:  Try to avoid checking of `strlen()` in for loop, if possible. It gets evaluated every iteration. If the string is not going to change, you can evaluate it once, store in a variable (say `len_name1`) & use that variable as `i<len_name1`, instead of function call in loop.

NOTE2: If there are multiple break statements in the inner for loop & you want to differentiate between the 2 break statement, you can set a flag just before `break`ing & based on its value, instead of using `if(j<strlen(name2))`.